# Regular Expression for a Kibana Search

Tags: regex, kibana

I am trying to create a regular expression search within Kibana. I am new to regex and new to kibana, but the solution to this issue should not be too complex.

Right now I am filtering through the "message" field of a query of searches for the specific text `Max Memory Used`. Currently the search is returning all messages with that text field. However, the "Max Memory Used" phrase is followed by a statistic for example `Max Memory Used: 65 MB`. The issue I am having is that I do not know how to create the regex search to return both the `Max Memory Used`, and the `__ MB`, as the number of MB used is different every time.

The current used filter reads `"Max Memory Used"` in the search field.

Comment: When I use the filter ```message:"Max Memory Used: "/[0-9]{1,3}/" MB"``` Kibana returns a search for every log that has a number in it period... The reasoning for this is because it reads the ```Max Memory Used```, the ```/[0-9]{1,3}/```, and the "MB" as 3 separate filters, how can i make them 1 joint filter?

Comment: Put `MB` also inside forward slashes something like: `"/Max Memory Used: [0-9]{1,3} MB/"`

Comment: Is your problem solved @ChandlerCree?

Answer (score 1):

Try the regex below:

```
/^\bMax\b \bMemory\b \bUsed\b: \d+? [MmKkGgTt]?[Bb]$/
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

> **`^`** - Represents the start of the given test String.
>
> **`\b`** - Represents the word boundary.
>
> **`\d+?`** - Represents the digit class matching one or more digits lazily.
>
> **`[MmKkGgTt]?`** - Represents a character matching the characters among the given class zero or one time. Since the size can be in `KB`, `GB`, `MB` or even just `B`. You can add them accordingly.
>
> **`$`** - Represents end of the given test String.

[image: pictorial representation]

You can find the demo of the above regex [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/QnBER2/1)

Comment: When I try the above Regex I get this error ```Discover: parse_exception: Encountered " "^" "^ "" at line 1, column 8. Was expecting one of: <BAREOPER> ... "(" ... "*" ... <QUOTED> ... <TERM> …```

Comment: I updated the regex. Try it again using the backslashes.O else if you're passin as string pass this: `"/^\\bMax\\b \\bMemory\\b \\bUsed\\b: \\d*? [MmKkGgTt]?[Bb]$/"` escaping the forward slashes

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Max Memory Used: [0-9]+ MB
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/SZ5Vbd/1). `[0-9]+` will match one or more digits.